# ng-bootstrap popover does not close instead it repositions slightly

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular-template

I am using the angular 2 bootstrap 4 module.

I want to show a popover element with a yes and no button to delete something.

When I click the no button the popover should close.

That does not happen instead the popover repositions slighty as if it would be re-initialized...

I have no clue whats happening.

Anyone can help?

```
<button[ngbPopover]="popContent" popoverTitle="You really wanna delete this item?">Delete</button>

<template #popContent>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button (click)="delete(s.id)">Yes</button>
        <button (click)="popContent.close()">No</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify `triggers` attribute with `manual` value on `popover` element which will make popover to open on manual event. By default trigger set to `click`.

**Markup**

```
<button [ngbPopover]="popContent" 
  triggers="manual" 
  #p="ngbPopover"
  (click)="p.toggle()"
  popoverTitle="You really wanna delete item?">
     Delete
</button>

<template #popContent>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button (click)="delete(s.id)">Yes</button>
        <button (click)="p.close()">No</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FjpCSEGIjW4YWwgfRAjQ?p=preview)

Comment: I did that triggers="manual" and (click)="p.toggle()" #p="ngbPopover" [ngbPopover]="popContent" now the Delete button toggles but the No button does not close the popover! although the local reference seems right. I get no error in the console clicking the No button. Thats a bad API... Is it maybe not possible at all to close the popover from within a template-tag? I can not find any such a use case here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover

Comment: Try `p.close` instead. I made this working yesterday

Comment: Does not work! I do p.close().  p.close makes no sense if close is a function. It seems I can not reference the popover instance from within that template #popContent. I tried (click)="p.close()" and (click)="popContent.close()" both work not. I get the error now:  EXCEPTION: self.parent._TemplateRef_56_4.close is not a function

Comment: So you return tomorrow and tell me what you found out?

Comment: Then sleep well ;-)

Comment: yes it works in your plunkr, but not in my code :/ error_handler.js:47ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'close' of undefinedErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:47
error_handler.js:50ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:50
error_handler.js:51TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined

Comment: So the 'p' variable is undefined or somehow not known... I will mark your plunkr as solution and must find the error in my project...

Comment: @Elisabeth which version of bootstrap you are using?

Comment: bootstrap 4         "raw": "bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.5",

Comment: Thanks for the help, to put the template in the td-tag of the ngfor helped!